# How to do updates over 3 classes

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Usually we update some data from `ClassB` to `ClassA` (so over 2 classes) – by using events or delegates.

What I need to do is to update `ClassA` from `ClassC` (`ClassC` is opened through `ClassA` and `ClassB`). So no direct access from `ClassC` to `ClassA`.

How is this possible, such that I would not need to do any additional code in `ClassB`?

Example:

```
class ClassA
{
    private void OpenClassB() 
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.WorkOnB();
    }

    public void UpdatingFromClassC()
    {
        // I have to call this method from ClassC (from method WorkOnC)
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public void WorkOnB()
    {
        //...
        //and:
        OpenClassC();
    }

    private void OpenClassC()
    {
        ClassC c  = new ClassC();
        c.WorkOnC();
    }
}

class ClassC
{
    public void WorkOnC()
    {
        //call UpdatingFromClassC() method on form1 from here!
    }
}
```

What I don't like is to pass Form1's reference. I have to use events or delegates – best option possible.

### ---

Let me be more clear. I do windows forms. Here is an example of it with 2 classes:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    Class1 c1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (c1 == null)
        {
            c1 = new Class1();
            c1.OnDoWork += new Action(From_Class1_OnDoWork);
            c1.DoSomeWork();
        }
    }

    private void From_Class1_OnDoWork()
    {
        //put your code into here for refreshing
        MessageBox.Show("Form1 is being refreshed!");
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public event Action OnDoWork;
    public Class1()
    {
        //constructor 
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Do some work in Class 1");
        if (OnDoWork != null)
        {
            OnDoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create a nother Form (Form2), that would be opened from Class1. I have to wake up the method on Form1 from Form2 (or pass the data to it).

I hope you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without introducing code to `ClassB`, since by your very design, there is no direct communication between the instances of `ClassA` and `ClassC`. Since `ClassB` is the intermediary, it must convey some mechanism by which they can communicate.

The simplest solution would just be to pass a reference to the relevant `ClassA` instance to `ClassC` via `ClassB`. If this seems to you too much like unnecessary coupling, then yes, you should use a delegate that specifies an action to take (and encloses a reference to `ClassA`).

Comment: I agree with you regarding passing the reference. Alternatively the callback can be passed via an Action from A -> B -> C, but it would require modifying the signatures of B and C.

Comment: Now I pass the reference of ClassA to ClassC through ClassB - but this is not something I want. Whats why Iam asking is there any other possibility. How would look the code like (in basics) with a use of delegate?

Comment: @Mitja: You are misundertanding. Pass just the delegate UpdatingFromClassC(), not a reference to A in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

It feels liek the constructors to both C and B should be receiving an **Action** delegate argument, in this case a delegate to **UpdatingFromClassC()**. The exact mechanism need not be this, but from the description given seems most likely appropriate for this scenario.